# Get log on user in .net core worker service

Tags: c#, .net-core, background-service

I have a .net core 3.1.8 worker service.
Is there a way to access the username of the Windows user that is set as the log on user for this service?
I don't really see anything related to this in the documentation of the background service.
Tried googling, but google only really finds stuff related to HttpContext, which I obviously do not have in a background service.

I only really need this for logging purposes, as in set the creator/modifying user in the DB when something is inserted/updated through the service, so my current solution is putting a serviceUserName property in appsettings.json and read it from there, but that just feels... dirty?

Comment: do you tried `Environment.UserName`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Ohh, seems like I started digging too deep. It seems to work.Thanks.

Comment: Or [Thread.CurrentPrincipatl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal?view=netcore-3.1), [WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.getcurrent?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the comments, you can get user name of current thread with:

```
Environment.UserName
```

#### Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can get the current user.

- [Environment.UserName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username?view=netcore-3.1) will return just the user name
- [WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.getcurrent?view=netcore-3.1) returns a [WindowsIdentity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity?view=netcore-3.1) object with the user's group memberships that also allows impersonation
- [Thread.CurrentPrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal?view=netcore-3.1) returns an [IPrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.iprincipal?view=netcore-3.1) object, mainly used in web applications or authentication libraries.